# Cookies are disappearing, can't figure out how

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, cookies

I have an ASP.NET/C# app.  In my server-side code, I'm setting a couple cookies: MyLogin and MySession.  In my C# code I'm adding add these code to the Response.Cookies with an expiration date a month from today.  After my C# method finishes, I see them come back in the response in fiddler.

However, in the JavaScript code that gets executed next they're missing.  I've searched for "document.cookie" in IE developer tools.  I found a couple JavaScript functions that contain that string, but they're not doing anything with the cookies in question.  Any idea what's happening to them?

-Eric

Comment: Could they be [HttpOnly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#HttpOnly_cookie) cookies?

Comment: Thanks for the link to the article, that sounded like a likely answer.  However, in my C# code I'm seeing MyLogin.HttpOnly is false, so apparently that's not it.